# Enhance and remove redundant length check in while Loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a piece of code as below:

```
 while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {

                identityJmPojo.setIdentity(line[0]);
                identityJmPojo.setJM(line.length  > 1 ? line[1] : jsonValue);

                identityJmList.add(identityJmPojo);
                size = identityJmList.size();

                switch (size) {
                    case STEP:
                        counter = counter + STEP;
                        payloadEngine.prepareJson(identityJmList, uploaderPoolService);
                        identityJmList.clear();

                        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
                        logger.info("=================== Time taken to read " + STEP + " records from CSV: " + elapsedTime + " and total records read: " + counter + "===================");
                        break;
                }

            }
```

I am reading hundreds of billions of records from a CSV and the speed is business critical.

now for the statement:

```
identityJmPojo.setJM(line.length  > 1 ? line[1] : jsonValue);
```

The business defined consideration is if line.length is > 1 in the first iteration, it would be same for nth iteration and so I want to remove the redundant condition checking in every loop iteration. Just somehow set this for once and never use the ternary operator again.

Any hints or head ons would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you read the first line, calc the value for setJM(), and then read the whole file from the beginning.  You can then remove the ternary operator line, and don't have to replace it with any "if first line then...".

Comment: you could extract the first read, which would lengthen the code, but remove the condition for `identityJmPojo.setJM`

Comment: what is this identityJmList? Is it an arraylist or linkedlist

Comment: What is the type of `line`? Intuitively it's a String, but you access it like an array.

Comment: Its an array of string

Comment: I think @SteveSmith has a point here

Comment: Besides fixing that redundant check: Measure, how long it takes. I'm pretty sure your logging takes waaaay more time than your statement. Also: If you want measure elapsing time for performance, use nanoTime, System.currentTimeMillis is used for current time.

Comment: I agree logging takes much time, but I am using this for benchmarks and the actual logging will be handed to a rolling logger with a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I should note that unless the `setJM()` method is particularly expensive, this doesn't look like a strong candidate for optimisation. Run your code in a profiler and find out where it's really spending time before deciding this is the right place to focus your efforts.

Only guessing about the kind of processing you're doing - but I wouldn't be surprised if the bottleneck was disk IO. Time `cat inputfile > /dev/null` -- that will give you an idea of how long it takes to simply get the bytes off the disk (but be careful interpreting this, because filesystem memory caching will confuse matters). Similarly time the simplest program generating simulated output data, writing to disk.

---

Two very simple options, and they're fairly obvious:

**Handle the first line before you enter the loop**:

```
 line = reader.readNext();
 if(line != null) {
     stuffToDoOnlyOnFirstLine(...);
 }
 while(line != null) {
     stuffToDoOnAllLines(...);
     line = reader.readNext();
 }
```

It may feel cludgy to have two `reader.readNext()`s, but it's a well-established pattern called "read-ahead, read-until".

**Flag to indicate that the job's been done**

```
 boolean processedFirstLine = false;

 while(...) {
      ...
      if(!processedFirstLine) {
           stuffToDoOnFirstLine(...);
           lineLengthNoted = true;
      }
      ...
 }
```

You could get fancier and more OO by putting the capability into a class:

```
   class OnceOnlyThingDoer {
        private boolean done = false;

        public OnceOnlyThingDoer(...) {
            // set member variables e.g. the target POJO
        }

        public void record(int[] line) {
            if(!done) {
                doTheThing(line); // e.g. call your method on the target POJO
                done = true;
            }

        }
   }
```

You can do similarly neat things using lambdas, but I assume if you were comfortable with lambdas you wouldn't have asked this question.

```
@Test
public void writesOnlyOnce() {
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();

    Consumer<Supplier<Integer>> consumer = consumeOnlyOnce(num -> output.add(num));

    consumer.accept(() -> 5); // body of supplier could be much more complex
    consumer.accept(() -> 3);

    assertThat(output, is(Collections.singletonList(5)));

}

public Consumer<Supplier<Integer>> consumeOnlyOnce(Consumer<Integer> handler) {
    final boolean[] done = new boolean[] { false };

    return supplier -> {
        if (!done[0]) {
            handler.accept(supplier.get());
        }
        done[0] = true;
    };
}
```

The key here is that we're passing a `Supplier` function. Its body might be complex and expensive to be run, but it is only run when `supplier.get()` is called, which is guarded by `done`. Unfortunately in Java we can't use a non-final out-of-scope variable inside a lambda, so to track state we need to use something mutable, hence the one-element `int[]` array.

Comment: Great insight, I am using Java 7 and haven't gotten a chance to work with Lambdas before. Going for a tut!

Answer (score -1):

You can use do - while loop:

```
    line = reader.readNext();
    boolean useLine = line.length > 1;
    do {

        identityJmPojo.setIdentity(line[0]);
        identityJmPojo.setJM(useLine ? line[1] : jsonValue);
        ....
        line = reader.readNext();
    } while(line != null);
```